Como puedo dejar fijo un recorrido y que por encima un punto se mueva en Plotly
Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de física, para ser especifico, un tiro oblicuo. Y me gustaría que en el grafico se pueda observar el recorrido que tendrá mi objeto y con un slider poder visualizar un punto que se mueva sobre ese recorrido. Estoy trabajando con Python y estoy utilizando Plotly. En principio pense que con añadir un Scatter como recorrido y luego utilizar los frames para el objecto alcanzaría, pero al momento de iniciar la animación el recorrido fijo desaparece.
A continuacion dejo el codigo; los datos del DataFrame estan mas arriba (estoy trabajando con Jupyter):
#Data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y, 't': t})

#Create figure
fig = go.Figure(
#Add trace
data = [go.Scatter(x=df['x'], y=df['y'], mode='lines', name='Projectile Path', marker_color='blue')],

#Add layout
layout = go.Layout(
    title='Oblique Shot',
    xaxis=dict(title='x (m)', range=[df['x'].min(), df['x'].max()]),
    yaxis=dict(title='y (m)', range=[df['y'].min(), df['y'].max() + 1]),        
    template='plotly_dark',
    #Add buttons
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            type="buttons",
            buttons=[
                dict(label="Play",
                    method="animate",
                    args=[None]),
                dict(label="Pause",
                    method="animate",
                    args=[None])
            ],
            bgcolor='black',
            bordercolor='white',
            borderwidth=1,
            direction='left',
            pad= {"r": 10, "t": 40, "b": 10, "l": 10},
            showactive=False,
            x=0.1,
            xanchor='right',
            y=0,
            yanchor='top'
        )
    ],
    #Add slider
    sliders=[
        dict(
            active=0,
            steps=[],
            pad={"r": 10, "t": 40, "b": 10, "l": 10},
            x=0.1,
            xanchor='left',
            y=0,
            yanchor='top',
            len=0.9,
            currentvalue=dict(
                font=dict(size=10),
                prefix='Time (s): ',
                visible=True,
                xanchor='left'
            )
        )
    ]
),
#Add frames
frames=[]
)

#Create frames
aframes = []
asteps = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    t = row['t']
    x = row['x']
    y = row['y']

    # Create a marker for this time value
    scatter_marker = go.Scatter(x=[x], y=[y], mode='markers', name='Projectile Marker', marker=dict(color='red', size=10))

    # Create a frame
    frame = go.Frame(data=[scatter_marker], name=str(t))

    # Add the frame to the figure
    aframes.append(frame)

    #Create steps
    slider_step = {
    "args": [
        [t],
        {"frame": {"duration": 200, "redraw": True},
        "mode": "immediate",
        "transition": {"duration": 300}}
    ],
    "label": round(t, 2),
    "method": "animate"
    }
    asteps.append(slider_step)

#Add frames
fig.frames = aframes
#Add steps
fig.layout.sliders[0].steps = asteps

#Show figure
fig.show()

